# How can i make an element from a bottom stacking context stays in front of another higher stacking context?

Tags: html, css

How can i make that an element contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order appears in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order ?

e.g:

HTML:

```
<div class="Parent-1"></div>

<div class="Parent-2">

    <div class="pepe"></div>
    <div class="pepin"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Parent-1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: green;
}

.Parent-2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: red;
}

.pepe, .pepin{        
    background-color: blue;
}

.pepin{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

this is what i have (this is what it's suppose to happen):
[image]

this is what i want:
[image]

Bare in mind that i can't change the elemnts order in HTML neither remove the z-index in Parents element

Comment: you are right sorry i miss positioned in the example i fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. This image from [MDN's explanation about stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) explains it well:

[image]

There has been talk about escaping stacking context using `position: fixed` but it seems this is not happening just yet (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zNPm/3/) and the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491859/does-position-fixed-create-a-new-stacking-context-for-z-indicies) that generated it).

**Alternate Solution:**

For you, a possible alternative solution would be to nest `Parent-1` inside `Parent-2` and then use `position: absolute` to put `Parent-1` wherever you want it.

Comment: the alternate solution is not a yes yes solution, but it works to me, so thx